# Sharpening extrema using DensityPlot

Tags: visualization

I have a data set where I really care mainly about visualizing the highest and lowest areas. DensityPlot suits my needs well, but ideally the maxima and minima would pop more from the rest of the data. I know that DensityPlot scales the data from your function to between zero and one before coloring it accordingly. I'd like to use a scaling that has more meat in the middle than theirs. So I was thinking I could take their scaling, and use it as an input to for example

```
 (x-0.5)^3/8,
```

which has the properties `f[0]=0` and `f[1]=1`, but  is better distributed for my purpose. Then I'd pass these values to the colorizer.

Can't really figure out how to do this though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look at the `ColorFunction` option. For example: `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][(# - .5)^(3/8)] &)`

Comment: @mfvonh - please consider expanding on your comment as an answer with some graphical examples.

Answer (score 2):

Many plotting functions accept the `ColorFunction` argument, which you can use to pass a function that will generate colors for each plotted point. Here is an example:

```
ColorData[ "LakeColors" ]
```

[image]

It is a function that returns color values:

```
ColorData[ "LakeColors" ][ .5 ]
```

> RGBColor[ 0.663226 , 0.687282 , 0.911765 ]

The `{0,1}` means this function will map any value in the range [0, 1] to the depicted color spectrum. By default, functions that accept the `ColorFunction` option rescale their values to this range, but you can prevent this with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. In general you would not use this unless you are passing in a custom color function with a different domain. There are also "indexed" color schemes that are appropriate for discrete data. See `Color Schemes` in the documentation.

`"LakeColors"` is the default color scheme for `DensityPlot`:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sin[ x ] Sin[ y ], { x , -4 , 4 } ,
 { y, -3 , 3 } ]
```

[image]

We can change that with the option:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sin[ x ] Sin[ y ], { x , -4 , 4 } ,
 { y, -3 , 3 } ,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[ "SunsetColors" ] ]
```

[image]

Similarly, we can add a rescaling step:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sin[ x ] Sin[ y ], { x , -4 , 4 } ,
 { y, -3 , 3 } ,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][#^(3/8)] &) ]
```

[image]

I removed the `- .5` from your method because that creates negative values here. Any transformation you attach to a `ColorFunction` option should map from [0, 1] to [0, 1] when you are using default color functions.